# Automatic creation of "possible duplicate of X" should add a linked question under "Linked"

Tags: feature-request

When voting to close as duplicate, the system automatically creates the "possible duplicate" comment, with a link to the possible duplicate question. However, it fails to add a "linked question" to the Linked section to the right.

[Take this question as an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817865/how-can-i-detect-when-a-windows-machine-sleeps-and-awakes-in-c) Screenshot:

[image]

When the necessary amount of close votes have been cast, the system automatically creates the "Possible Duplicate:" box in the question body. When that happens, the Linked question is properly associated.

I think it should still create the Linked question when the autogenerated comment is created. That way, visitors to a question that isn't completely closed will still plainly see the link.

## Why?

Mainly, it's a matter of consistency. Why shouldn't every linked question be counted equally?

Furthermore, I believe this feature would serve two purposes:

1. Visitors trying to solve a specific problem will be flipping through pages as fast as they can to find a solution. If they come across a question with no answers, they are not likely to bother to read the comments. In the most likely case of one linked duplicate question, only a single link will appear under "Linked". This will stand out more than comments. If they see a similarly titled Linked question (or "duplicate" question), they might click it and find their solution.
2. Quickly glancing under "Linked" will help moderators and users that can cast close votes to determine whether the question is duplicate.

Comment: Suppose it's not really a duplicate? Should the link still show?

Comment: they're linked when the question is closed

Comment: @jmort253: Yes, because it's still linked. Showing the link under the "Linked" section doesn't enforce that it's a duplicate.

Comment: @BenBrocka: I mentioned that in my question. Still, the casual observer might benefit from the link under the "Linked" section. It increases the chance that they might glance over and notice, "Hey, this is a duplicate!"

Comment: If you yourself put a link in the comments to another question, does it show up as linked then? Note: I'm not talking about close votes, just regular, everyday comments that link to other SO questions.

Comment: @jmort253 yep, it's automatic for all comments except the automatic ones apparently. I hadn't noticed that, maybe it's because they're deleted when the post is closed?

Comment: @SimpleCoder, could you explain in your feature request how this adds value? This will help the SE team more quickly determine if this is worth it, and help them spend less time waiting for an update.

Comment: @jmort253: I've added two reasons. Like I mention in my edit, however, it's mostly a matter of consistency and attention to detail.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes, there is an auto-generated comment the first time someone marks a question as a duplicate.

Comment: Right, I thought you were talking about after the actual close. My mistake.